# Conversion of nested collections to interfaces

Tags: c#

Why? Surely I do not need a user defined conversion as `List(T)` is an `IList(T)` and `HashSet(T)` is an `IEnumerable(T)`. Thanks.

> Cannot implicitly convert type '`System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<string>>`' to '`System.Collections.Generic.IList<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>>`'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

```
class Program {

    static IList<IEnumerable<string>> GetSet() {
        return new List<HashSet<string>>();
    }

}
```

Comment: Because `IList` is invariant (or, more specifically, it's not covariant) in its type parameter. You could return `List<HashSet<string>>` if the declared return type of the method was, for example, `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>>`.

Comment: In other words: The problem is there are conflicting rules about what can be passed into the list's methods. `IList<IEnumerable<string>>` declares that you can call `Add` with any `IEnumerable<string>`, but `List<HashSet<string>>` says it must be a HashSet. However, you could create a `List<IEnumerable<string>>` and just add HashSets to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `IList<T>` is invariant.

To illustrate why this is a problem, consider the following example:

> An `IList<T>` offers for instance a method to `Add(T object)` an `IEnumerable<string>`, which would conflict with your constructor expression `new List<HashSet<string>>()`. It would imply that I could call your `program.GetSet()` and add a `new ArrayList<string>()`, but your constructed instance will not allow it, since it has a contract that it only contains `HashSet<string>` instances (what would you return when one asks the content of the `GetSet()` containing an `ArrayList<T>`?

The fact that the typeparameter is doubly nested doesn't matter. For instance `IList<Object>` is not a superclass of `IList<FooClass>` either.

---

This is not the case with `IEnumerable<T>` itself (meaning that `IEnumerable<T>` is a `IEnumerable<SuperT>` as well), since the only functionality of an `IEnumerable<T>` is to output values. Which is allowed due to the Liskov Substitution Principle.

> The principle says that when walking down in a class hierarchy, the
>   return types can only become more general (super classes/interfaces)
>   and the parameter types can only become more specific (sub
>   classes/interfaces).

---

C# offers tools to deal with this principle (called variance) by using the `in` and `out` keywords in the generic type declaration.

For instance if you are sure that a `Foo<SubT>` is a `Foo<T>` as well, you can define this as:

```
public class Foo<out T> {

    T getResult () {
        //do something
    }

}
```

In that case `T` is covariant with respect to `Foo`. In case a type parameter is only used as input, it can be further specified. For instance `Bar<T>` is clearly a special case of `Bar<SubT>` in the following definition:

```
public class Bar<in T> {

    void setParameter(T parameter) {
        //do something
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think what I was really needing is a simple explanation of variance - contravariance and covariance - in the context of C# generics which I have found [here](http://csharp.2000things.com/category/interfaces/) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183%28v=vs.120%29.aspx):

The error message did not really lead me to that but now I will summarise:

**Contravariance**

A generic class, which of course is a template for a class rather than a class definition, can be made *contravariant* using the *in* keyword. A contravariant class allows assignments from a base class instance to a derived class instance ie BorderCollie = Dog

```
public interface AllowAssignmentsFromBaseToDerived<in T>
```

**Covariance**

A generic class can be made *covariant* using the *out* keyword. A covariant class allows assignments from a derived class instance to a base class instance ie Dog = BorderCollie

```
public interface AllowAssignmentsFromDerivedToBase<out T>
```

Variance is supported for array types since C# 1.0 and delegate types since C# 2.0, as well as generic type arguments since C# 4.0.

Would be nice to have had more responses to cover more points that I have missed, still feel a bit under informed.

More info lifted from [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx):

> **How can I create variant generic interfaces and delegates myself?**
>
> The out keyword marks a type parameter as covariant, and the in
>   keyword marks it as contravariant. The two most important rules to
>   remember:
>
> 1. You can mark a generic type parameter as covariant if it is used only
>      as a method return type and is not used as a type of formal method
>      parameters.
> 2. And vice versa, you can mark a type as contravariant if it
>      is used only as a type of formal method parameters and not used as a
>      method return type.

```
    interface IVariant<out R, in A>
    {
        // These methods satisfy the rules.
        R GetR();
        void SetA(A sampleArg);
        R GetRSetA(A sampleArg);

        // And these don’t.
        // A GetA();
        // void SetR(R sampleArg);
        // A GetASetR(R sampleArg);
    }
```

Also, if you extend a variant generic interface it is invariant by default. You would need to specify In or Out as required.

Finally, as my explanation will be woefully inadequate try [Eric Lippert's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/30/what-s-the-difference-between-covariance-and-assignment-compatibility.aspx)